Yolov8 bug with path yaml
my yolov8 can't find the yaml folder
code
bug
bug
ultraliticks
I tried to change the / sign to , it didn’t help, I used os and os.join, it still didn’t help, it constantly creates a zip folder next to the yaml file and i change ultraliticks yaml file

It is preferable to post the code and full error log in text instead of screenshots. For Windows paths try to use all of them in the form r"". For instance: r"C:\Chiken\dataset\data.yaml".
